# Repeat a specific command for all files located in a folder

Tags: loops, batch-file

I need a script that will go into a directory, execute the command on each file, i tried some commands in a batch file, but i can't figure it out :)

```
john-wick-parse serialize file_route/filename_with_no_extention
```

Comment: You'd generally use a [tag:for-loop] for that, e.g. `for %%i in (*) do Command CommandLineOptions`. Open a Command Prompt window and enter `for /?` to read the usage information for the `for` command. In this case you'd be replacing what would generally be the file name in your `Command...` with `"%%i"`.

Answer (score 0):

### Bash shell *for* loops

```
for f in file1 file2 file3 file5
do
    echo "We are now processing... $f"
    # do something on $f
done
```

And if you want, you can declare a variable containing the path to the files, one on each line, something like this:

```
FILES="file1
/path/to/file2
/etc/resolv.conf"
for f in $FILES
do
    echo "We are now processing... $f"
    # do something on $f
done
```

There's all sort of options for that, like selecting all files with a certain extension.

So if you were to use the first option:

### Our files

```
-- my_folder
    -- file1
    -- file2
    -- file3
    -- etc
```

### Our code

```
cd /path/to/my_folder

for f in file1 file2 file3 file5
do
    echo "We are now processing... $f"
    # do something on $f
done
```

Comment: what i write instead of "file1, file2, ecc?"

Comment: This answer is not a [[tag:batch-file]] as per the OP tags, which is a [[tag:windows-10]] OS, as per the comments. There is no [[tag:sh]], [[tag:shell]] or [[tag:bash]] tag.